# Determine clicked button in javafx

Tags: java, button, javafx, refactoring, fxml

I have a piece of code that response to click on buttons in `desktop application`. I have two buttons that do the same thing: they copy to clipboard information from the text field to the left. I have tied a`method to each button`. But it looks like shit:

```
@FXML
public void copyToClipboardRaw() {
    if(code == null || code.isEmpty()) {
        nothingToCopyAlert();
    } else {
        Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString(rawCode.getText());
        clipboard.setContent(content);
    }
}

@FXML
public void copyToClipboardHTML() {
    if(code == null || code.isEmpty()) {
        nothingToCopyAlert();
    } else {
        Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString(codeForHTML.getText());
        clipboard.setContent(content);
    }
}
```

How can I bind one method to all buttons and determine in this method which button was clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not factor out the common code into a single method:

```
@FXML
public void copyToClipboardRaw() {
    copyToClipboard(rawCode);
}

@FXML
public void copyToClipboardHTML() {
    copyToClipboard(codeForHTML);
}

private void copyToClipboard(TextField source) {
    if(code == null || code.isEmpty()) {
        nothingToCopyAlert();
    } else {
        Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString(source.getText());
        clipboard.setContent(content);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is so much simple that I feel myself like absolute dummy :)

Answer (score 4):

You may use the text property of the buttons, or use `userData` property as well. For example:

```
<Button text="Copy as raw" userData="raw" onAction="#copyToClipboard" />
<Button text="Copy as HTML" userData="html" onAction="#copyToClipboard" />
```

and in controller class

```
@FXML
private void copyToClipboard( ActionEvent event )
{
    Button button = (Button) event.getSource();
    String type = button.getUserData();
    if ("html".equals(type)) {
        // copy as html
    } else if ("raw".equals(type)) {
        // copy as raw
    }
}
```